# how to achieve expanded element when clicked and it collapse when clicked anywhere else on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image: the cliked state when the field is expanded to show the text input]

how should i go about adding this functionality i want the element text to get bigger and the textinput to appear see image however i also want only one element to be expanded at a time so when the user taps on anther element the first one should collapse or even if they clicke anywhere else on the screen it should collapse

Comment: What are you ideas? Could you post any demo markup of your progress?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a parent component act as a controller. Define a handler function that changes what 'option' is open. Place all of the 'option' components in a div. Use the handler function in the 'onClick' event of the 'options' and the containing div. If you're in the 'option' pass the option id and use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the click event of the containing div from firing. If you're in the div pass a null value. Here's an example:

```
class Option extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="Option"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          this.props.clickHandler(this.props.optionId)
        }}
      >
        {'Hello '}{this.props.name}
        {this.props.open ? (
          <div>
            {'More text'}
          </div>
          ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { openOptionId: null };
  }

  clickHandler = (optionId) => {
    console.log(optionId);
    this.setState({
      openOptionId: optionId || null
    });
  }

  render() {

    const options = [
      {optionId: 1, name: 'World'},
      {optionId: 2, name: 'Bob'},
      {optionId: 3, name: 'React'}
    ]
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div
          onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}
        >
          {options.map((option) => {
            return (
              <Option
                optionId={option.optionId}
                open={this.state.openOptionId === option.optionId ? true : false}
                name={name}
                clickHandler={this.clickHandler}
              />
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zwygac24/1/

Comment: how would i go about doing it in react native